# disallowing links in Magento contact form

Tags: magento-1, ce-1.7.0.2, contact-us, ce-1.9.3.1

I had a working "disallow links" in the contact form in my 1.7.0.2

this was the basic code and did its job:

```
if(preg_match('/www\.|http:|https:/i',$post['comment']){
    $error = true;
}
```

it was in `Indexcontroller.php` and worked well. I them added the same code (on the same Linux server) in the same file on Magento 1.9.3.1  It causes a white screen.

Cache is disabled.

I understand that this is not the ideal way of achieving this, I will move this file to Local pool once it is working.

Comment: Welcome to the SE Paul , whenever you post the question add Error logs and sample code that you tried so we can easily debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new module and extend indexController in it.

Create **Namespace_Customcontact.xml** at **app/etc/modules/Namespace_Customcontact.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Customcontact>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Namespace_Customcontact>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Add **config.xml** file at **app/code/local/Namespace/Customcontact/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Customcontact>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Customcontact>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customcontact>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Customcontact before="Mage_Contacts">Namespace_Customcontact</Namespace_Customcontact>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customcontact>
        </routers>
    </frontend> 
</config>
```

Create controller file at And the controller: **app/code/local/Namespace/Customcontact/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Contacts') . DS . 'IndexController.php';
class Namespace_Customcontact_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function postAction()
    {
      // add your code here

        $regex = '/(((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/)|(www\.))[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\:[0-9]+)?(\/\S*)?/';
        if(preg_match($regex, $text)) {
            $error = true;
        }
    }
}
```